# How to create a scatter plot from a multi-column data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, scatter-plot

I'm trying to produce a scatter plot of laboratory mesurments stored in a data frame.

The data I use looks like this:

```
> print(df)
   day         val1         val2         val3
1    1      9.26875     11.34072     11.26673
2    2     48.47862     48.35817     48.68534
3    3    140.17682    141.09102    142.95175
4    4    313.43012    313.69816    312.97293
```

Each row shows which measurement were done for each day.

I would like to produce a scatter plot that would show just that.
The final result would look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk0lJ.png).

I've found countless exemples about how to make a scatter plot [treating each column as a different object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109822/r-creating-scatter-plot-from-data-frame), which is *not* what I want to do.

The closest thing I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r), but the explaination is not clear, and I don't understand why the packages `reshape2`, and `ggplot2` are required for this task.

Can anyone please give me any directions about that?

Best regards.

Comment: See http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html, past example one, and see if you can melt your dataframe down so your val1, val2, val3 are like the cylinders factor in the example.

Comment: Linked post has many solutions. We need `reshape2` to reshape from wide-to-long format, then use ggplot to plot. There is also `matplot` function, look through all the answers, not all require ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

While not required, libraries give certain functionality that is not necessarily present or easy to find in base R.  For example you can do a simple scatter plot with your dataframe:

```
df$day <- as.factor(df$day)
df <- melt(df)
plot(as.numeric(df$day),df$value)
```

[image: boring plot]

As you can see this generic plot can be achieved with a melt to get your data into long format with 1 column for your factors and 1 column for your values.  However with a few  lines of `ggplot` you can create a simple graph that is arguably more informative with only a little extra effort.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=day,y=value, colour = variable)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .3))
```

[image: ggplot]

You can learn more about ggplot2 [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. It's very short indeed! I'll need time to wrap my head around this. This isn't easy to understand for a newcomer like myself.

Comment: Good luck. It can be overwhelming at first, so it's not a bad idea to start with the base functions.