# Dot plot of all columns in R against the column number

Tags: r, plot, multiple-columns, dot

Suppose I have a data frame like below

```
mydf=data.frame(method=factor(1:10), x1=rpois(10,2), x2=round(rnorm(10),3), x3=rgeom(10,0.3))
```

I would like to make a dot plot of all variables from `X1` through `X3` in the same figure. I tried the following code

```
plot(mydf$x1~rep(1,10), xlab="", ylab = "")
plot(mydf$x2~rep(2,10), xlab="", ylab = "")
plot(mydf$x3~rep(3,10), xlab="", ylab = "")
```

How can I plot them in single figure?

Comment: A stack of options over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109822/r-creating-scatter-plot-from-data-frame/15112044

Comment: @IanCampbell - pun unintended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you had in mind, but maybe give `ggplot` a try?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot)
mydf %>% 
   pivot_longer(-method, names_to = "variable") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Otherwise, just use `points` instead of `plot`:

```
plot(mydf$x1~rep(1,10), xlab="", ylab = "", xlim = c(0.5,3.5), ylim = range(mydf[,2:4]), xaxt = 'n')
points(mydf$x2~rep(2,10))
points(mydf$x3~rep(3,10))
axis(1,at = 1:3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `matplot`.

```
matplot(t(mydf[-1]), pch=16, col=1, xaxt="n")
axis(1, 1:3, names(mydf[-1]))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
mydf=data.frame(method=factor(1:10), x1=rpois(10,2), x2=round(rnorm(10),3), x3=rgeom(10,0.3))
```